# How to dynamically set minDate in Materialize? (pure javascript only)

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, materialize

I have two Materialize datepickers

```
<input class="datepicker" id="start" type=text value="2021-05-12"/>
<input class="datepicker" id="end" type=text value="2021-05-25"/>
```

I want for goth of them dynamically set minDate and maxDate. In pure javascript. I initalize them in a loop

```
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
  
  elems.forEach(e => {
    console.log(e.id)
    datePicker[e.id] =  M.Datepicker.init(elems, datepickerOptions);

  })
```

but then I do not know how to access them correctly. None of these works.

```
//    datePicker["end"].modalEl.options.minDate =new Date("2021-05-15")
//        datePicker["end"].options.minDate =new Date("2021-05-15")
//    datePicker["end"].modalEl.minDate =new Date("2021-05-15")
//    datePicker["end"].el.minDate =new Date("2021-05-15")
//    datePicker["end"].el.options.minDate =new Date("2021-05-15")

//datePicker["end"].pickadate({
//datePicker["end"].modalEl.pickadate({
//  min: new Date("2021-05-15"),
//  max: new Date("2021-05-30")
//})
    
//    datePicker["end"].modalEl.close()
```

Could someone help me out? working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/1d359rj4/38/)

Comment: you can try `this.options.minDate = new Date("2021-05-17")`

Comment: works well, but I need to set up different values for datePicker["end"] and datePicker["start"]